# Textbox with TextChanged event doesn't bring the date in second enter

Tags: c#, textbox, textchanged

I have a `Textbox` with `TextChanged` event working very well if I enter the correct id. But if I enter a wrong id and the `MessageBox` appears in catch section, and then I try to enter a correct id, it keeps giving me the `MessageBox` error.

Here is my code:

```
private void Pro1txt_onChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        cmd1 = new SqlCommand(" SELECT  P_Name,P_Price,P_Quantity from Product where P_ID =  '" + Pro1txt.Text + "'", cn);
        cn.Open();
        DataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        DataReader.Read();
        ProdcutName1.Text = DataReader["P_Name"].ToString();
        UnitPrice1.Text = DataReader["P_Price"].ToString();
        Rem_Quantity1.Text = DataReader["P_Quantity"].ToString();

        if (Rem_Quantity1.Text =="0")
        {
            Req_Quantity1.Enabled = false;
        }             
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error","danget",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Hand);             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You query is vulnerable to SQL Injection. You should use `Parameters`

For example:

```
cmd1 = new SqlCommand(" SELECT  P_Name,P_Price,P_Quantity from Product where P_ID =  @id", cn);
cmd1.Parameters.Clear();
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(Pro1txt.Text);
cn.Open();
....
```

and try not to include messagebox in your catch block.. use finally to close your DB connection.

Search for query with parameters for more info.

Comment: Small Quation I want the columns in table comes to text box is your way will work

Answer (score 0):

First things first: this code is vulnerable to sql injection.

Then to offer a quick solution:
Do not display a dialog in a catch block.
Set a global flag to indicate your application state.
Then use that flag to display your message or not.

Comment: more explain my friend I don't understand you.